# Question about extended editions of movies

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just saw this question which was posted:

[Were any of the The Matrix movies released with extended editions?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94264/were-any-of-the-the-matrix-movies-released-with-extended-editions)

I'm curious why this was marked as off-topic?  I think the reason given was meant to deter people from asking where they could download or watch pirated content, but asking a question about extended editions seems like it should be allowed here.  Am I misunderstanding the reason for that use of "off-topic"?

Answer (score 3):

This close reason is for questions which are asking for a list of movies/TV shows or sources where they can buy/download them.

> Recommendation questions **asking for movies/TV-shows or resources to locate or watch** movie/TV content are off topic.

However, the reason that made me VTC that question was these two.

> And if so, in which boxset would they be found in?

and

> there's no mention of where those extended versions can be found

This is a borderline case where OP seems to be asking both if there were any extended versions and **where to find them if yes**. Editing these parts out can make this question on-topic here.

I've reopened the question with required edits.

Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Just so I can narrow it down, suppose I knew that one released version of Oceans 11 contains a commentary track with Brad Pitt and one did not (which is true, BTW).  If I wanted to find out which release contained the Pitt commentary, that would be off-topic because I'm asking where to find it?  If that's true, can we discuss whether we can be flexible with that requirement?  I can see in certain circumstances where that type of question could be paramount; such as fans who want to track down the last officially released version of Star Wars (aka Ep. IV) prior to Lucas' "enhancements".

Comment: Off-Topic: "Where can I buy or watch the version that has commentary?" On-Topic: "Which version has commentary?"